# Ajax post Error in Laravel between two post

Tags: ajax, laravel, post, routes

I have two code blocks those should yield same result but one works and one produces an HTTP 500 error.

This is the code that generates the error:

```
$('.dropify').dropify();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').dataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            method: 'POST',
            url : '{{ route('backend.master.jurusan.data') }}',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            }
        },
```

with defined route:

```
Route::post('/jurusan/data', 'JurusanController@getData')->name('jurusan.data');
```

while this one works perfectly:

```
$('.dropify').dropify();
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#datatable').dataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        ajax: {
            method: 'POST',
            url : '{{ route('backend.master.brand.data') }}',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
            }
        },
```

with the same route:

```
Route::post('/brand/data', 'BrandController@getData')->name('brand.data');
```

I don't understand why the first one generates this error:

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost/siakad/public/master/jurusan/data 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: route is ok . you have problem on your controller share code for `JurusanController@getData`¿

Comment: I posted the JurusanController@getData code, am i missing something there?

Answer (score 0):

@C2486

I hope this is what you mean: (this code is inside the JurusanController)

```
 public function getData()
{
    checkPermissionTo('view-master-data-list');

    $jurusan = Jurusan::all();

    return Datatables::of($jurusan)
            ->addColumn('action', function($jurusan) {
                $edit = '<a href="'. route('backend.master.jurusan.edit', $jurusan->id) .'" class="btn btn-sm btn-icon text-default tl-tip" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Edit"><i class="icon wb-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';
                $delete = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-icon text-danger tl-tip" data-href="'.route('backend.master.jurusan.destroy',$jurusan->id).'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete-modal" data-original-title="Delete"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>';

                return $edit.''.$delete;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
```

I copy paste the brand code into the jurusan and just change the route path.